# How do i create a 4 column layout in PySimpleGUI?

Tags: python-3.x, layout, multiple-columns, pysimplegui

I need to generate a section of a form with 4 columns. Since the sg.Table element doesn't accept other elements as content, I'm not sure how to achieve a side by side layout. I've been using PySimpleGUI for awhile, and I really like it. Studying the docs and playing around with examples but this issue has me stumped. I tried nested sg.Col elements but couldn't get this effect.

The point of using a table is to keep the columns aligned when the checkbox label length varies. No heading is required, the first column is just a single multi-line sg.Text label for the checkboxes in the other columns. Ideally the first column should be vertically aligned center.

The list of checkboxes will be generated based on a json configuration file.

```
                    [] bitchute1       [] vimeo7          [] youtube13
 Platforms:         [] bitchute.2      [] vimeo8hhhhhhh   [] youtube14 some size
                    [] bitchute...3    [] vimeo9jjj       [] youtube15
(select all         [] bitchute..4     [] vimeo10uiuyu    [] youtube16 whatever        
 that apply)        [] bitchute...5    [] vimeo11         [] youtube17            
                    [] bitchute6khjhj  [] vimeo12         [] youtube18
```

Of all the trials, I wasn't able to modify the example to keep variable length content aligned into columns like [the example](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#column-element-frame-tab-container-elements), which uses fixed width column data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put 4 columns at the same row with different elements, like `Text` and `Checkbox` elements.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

checks = [
    ["bitchute", "bitchute.2", "bitchute...3", "bitchute..4", "bitchute...5", "bitchute6khjhj"],
    ["vimeo7", "vimeo8hhhhhhh", "vimeo9jjj", "vimeo10uiuyu", "vimeo11", "vimeo12"],
    ["youtube13", "youtube14 some size","youtube15", "youtube16 whatever", "youtube17", "youtube18"],
]
column = [
    [[sg.Text('Platforms:\n\n(select all\nthat apply)')]]] + [
    [[sg.Checkbox(text, pad=(5, 0), key=('Check', j, i))] for i, text in enumerate(check)] for j, check in enumerate(checks)
]

layout = [[sg.Column(column[i]) for i in range(4)]]
sg.Window('Title', layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]